# Specify a schema using r2dbc-mssql

Tags: sql-server, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

**Is there any way to specify a default schema in a properties file using r2dbc-mssql?**

The connection works fine with:

```
spring:
  r2dbc:
    url: 'r2dbc:mssql://zzzzz.database.windows.net:1433/dbname'
    username: 'xxxxxx'
    password: 'xxxxxx'
```

but i have to use a static schema:

```
@Table("schemaname.foo")
public class Foo {

  @Id
  private Long id;
```

I've found something similar in r2dbc-postgresql:
https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql/issues/37

Comment: The default schema is a `USER` property, not a connection.

Comment: But why do JPA and hibernate have this option?
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema= schemaname

Comment: any updates in this matter?

Comment: i didn't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

In a Spring Boot application, I think you can execute a sql statement to switch schemas in the `@PostConstruct` method of a `@Configuration` class.

```java
@Configuration
class DatabaseConfig{

  @Autowired
  ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

  @PostConstruct
  void init(){
      Mono.from(connectionFactory.getConnection())
          .flatMap(c->c.createStatement("switch to your schema here, different database has different commands here").execute())
          .subscribe()
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. There doesn't seem to be a way other than adding it inside the `@Table` annotations.